# Windows8 App how to use Iframe

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I am trying load a html file inside my xaml file.I tried this

```
 <WebView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Name="WebView1" Margin="109,82,0,0"/>

string url = "ms-appdata:///local/assets/index.html";
WebView1.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

But is not working.I would like to know is this possible or is there any other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't point the `Uri` to a file in app data folder, try something like this instead:

```
using Windows.Storage;

StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("assets/index.html");
string html = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
WebView1.NavigateToString(html);
```